# Compile/Target SDK 22 - Handling permissions for API level 23?

Tags: android

I'm working on a library module with target/compile SDK 22, which needs some permissions. This module may be used in projects with SDK 23.

As in SDK 22 there is no method to request a permission at runtime, how would such projects handle the permissions? Would the permissions needed in the lib module not be granted (and therefore the concerning features not being available)?

My actual question is, do we have to upgrade the lib module to SDK 23 to properly work in projects with SDK 23 regarding permissions?

Comment: if your project is target to 22 api then you dont need to worry about marshmallow runtime permissions it will take care from manifest file

Comment: So, when the library (SDK 22) is used for an App (SDK 23) and runs on a device with SDK 23, the module will still work? And, the permissions needed, are yet granted on installation?

Comment: All the most new API version will can backward compatibility with old version

Comment: nope it wont work then as your app (sdk 23) needs to get run-time permissions esle change app sdk to 22